# Store MySQLite Database Online

Tags: java, database, eclipse, database-connection

I'm making a voting app in Java using Eclipse where the user votes for their favorite team. Right now I have a local MySQLite database that I am managing with the MySQLite Firefox extension. The votes are stored in the MySQLite database, then I have another java application that reads from the database and outputs the name of the team that got more votes. However, I would like to store this database online, so multiple people can vote at once, then the results are displayed. How can I go about doing this? I am guessing that I will need PHP, but I am having a hard time finding a tutorial on how to integrate a MySQLite database with PHP. I pretty much just need to store my database online. Everything is functional locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'll need more details but I'm assuming you have wrote a Standalone Java app, which is connected to you local SQLite Database.

Also, I think you don't want to distribute that app for everyone who wants to vote (would be better if they could vote via a website, right?).

In this case, you have to write a web application to provide both front-end and back-end of your app. You can pick one among many existing languages and frameworks (PHP is one of them), such as Java itself with some web framework, Ruby on Rails or Python/Django (just to depict some of them). Plus, I'd recommend you to use some other database such as MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Here are basic tutorials to you follow for some of the previously mentioned languages/framework:

- [Java (JSP)](https://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/)
- [PHP](http://cleartuts.blogspot.com/2014/12/simple-php-crud-operations-with-mysql.html)
- [Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

To deploy you app (i.e. put it online, you'll need a server). Honestly I'd recommend you to use [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) because the deploy process is really simple (just push your code using git) and you can run your app for free (if your app got really successful you may have to scale up the server and then you'll have to pay, but maybe that's not the case, right?).

So, pick up a language and framework, write your web app and deploy it to the server. Then you can have multiple access voting into the same database.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I changed to MySQL and I am now using MySQL workbench and phpmyadmin to manage my database. This way seems much easier for what I want to do. I think a MySQLite database is better fitted for a local database.